# Java/hibernate - c3p0 Error querying MariaDB

Tags: java, database, hibernate, tomcat, mariadb

Performing a query on mariaDB with hibernate framework, the system returns the message below:

> apr 04, 2019 4:43:48 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
>   INFORMAZIONI: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@3a29d5cf [ connectionPoolDataSource ->
>   apr 04, 2019 4:47:58 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   AVVERTENZA: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7a0c574a -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>   `

There are no further logs to understand the problem and, overall, it seems that this issue has been occurred suddenly...It is possible that some eclipse updates have changed the previous "good state"  of the code? Is there any method to perform a deep debug?

below the hibernate properties file:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://*******:****/anagraphic?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.username=*****
hibernate.connection.password=*****
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

hibernate.connection.autoReconnect=true
hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools= true
hibernate.minIdle=5
hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
hibernate.bytecode.provider = cglib
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary =true
hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer =true
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=20
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20

hibernate.cache.provider_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.user_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.user_second_level_cache=true

hibernate.c3p0.max_size=15
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=3
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=180
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=300
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=3
```

Comment: Can you check the c3p0 configuration with hibernate? Is it proper?

Comment: I have added the hibernate configuration properties; please tell me if you think something is wrong

Comment: I would like to specify that currently it seems that does not work hibernate with the webservice (restFull); more psecifically if i perform a query with hibernate from a generic main it works, but if i try to send a json to my ws  it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
It seems that the problem was caused after the take up of the daylight saving time.
The CEST time was the problem; the solution was to add the "serverTimeZone=UTC" to the connection string of maria db...below an example:

jdbc:mysql://*******:****/anagraphic?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC